# How To Solve UKLO Mandombe Problem

Tags: translation, syllables, african-languages

**Premise**

I was looking at a two-part problem from the 2021 UKLO titled "Mandombe". UKLO is a linguistics olympiad, which is mostly a code-breaking competition. In this problem, we were given a list of words in the Mandombe script and their corresponding transliterations in the Latin alphabet. Mandombe is a script used to write several languages of the Democratic Republic of the Congo.

For reference, I included both problems

**The Problems**
[image]

This first problem requires you to match the letters to the numbers.

[image]

This is the second question.

**My Question**

I figured out part 1), and checked it with the answer key. It is right. The key is below

[image]

However, I am confused how to do part 2)

**My Progress**

Based on the answers for part 1), I doubted that choices a), c) and d) were correct. For part 1), when there were two line segments, there was also a character with a single line segment. But I couldn't figure out how to eliminate b) or e).

**The Answer**

According to the answer key, the answer is e).

**My Question**

How would you figure out 2)?

Thank you for your time

Comment: This question stays and falls with the access to an external website that can go away without notice. please include the whole question here.

Comment: OK, I did. Thanks

Comment: Probably be better to migrate this to [puzzling.se]?

Comment: I originally posted it on there, but a user suggested it should be on here

Comment: "This would be a better fit at Linguistics SE. It is about problem-solving, but you do need a minimum level of linguistics knowledge to be able to approach these problems"

Comment: I thought Puzzling would be better, because despite the presence of the list of words in your picture, it didn't seem like they were actually relevant to the puzzle? Or maybe I'm just confused because you're showing excerpts of the puzzle in an odd order rather than all at once with the full text of the questions.

Comment: @curiousdannii The goal of the puzzle is to figure out how the Mandombe script works; without that you can't solve the second problem (which is based on the vowel glyphs). I agree that this could fit on Puzzling (though they seem to disagree) but as a general principle I think it's okay to have Linguistics Olympiad-style problems here too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numbers 1 through 5 are based on the five basic vowels in Mandombe: *i*, *u*, *e*, *o*, and *a*.

You can find the "closed triangle" shape of the number 4 in any syllables that contain an *o* vowel, like both syllables of Q (*mongo*) or the first syllable of I (*ngombe*). And similarly, you can find the "open triangle" or "Z" shape of the number 5 in any syllables that contain an *a* vowel, like both syllables of R (*maza*). (Similarly the single stroke for *i*, the double stroke for *u*, and the "fork" for *e*.)